# how we can connect aws rds postgres with active directory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory, amazon-rds

I want to connect an active directory(AD) with AWS RDS.

So, I can provide permission based on active directory users to access RDS database.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? [Using Windows Authentication with a Microsoft SQL Server DB Instance - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_SQLServerWinAuth.html)

Comment: Yes, like that but with PostgreSQL(using AWS RDS)

Comment: Like this? [Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL Supports User Authentication with Kerberos and Microsoft Active Directory](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/10/amazon-rds-for-postgresql-supports-user-authentication-with-kerberos-and-microsoft-active-directory/)